# Looking for datasets on automobile parts information for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, data-mining, data

I'm embarking on a machine learning project that requires a comprehensive dataset of automobile parts information. The goal is to train a model that can identify and categorize various auto parts, potentially aiding in tasks such as inventory management, parts recommendation, and compatibility checks.

Details:

Type of Data Needed: Detailed specifications, manufacturing data, part numbers, compatibility information, images of parts, and any related metadata.
Usage: To train a machine learning model for auto parts identification and classification.
Data Specificity: Data covering a wide range of vehicles, including different makes, models, and years, would be ideal.
What I've tried:

I've searched through online automotive forums and databases.
I’ve checked for open datasets on platforms like Kaggle and UCI Machine Learning Repository.
I’ve inquired with automobile parts retailers for any leads on datasets.
Could anyone guide me to where I might find such datasets, whether open-source or for purchase? Any help pointing me towards databases, repositories, or organizations that might have this type of information would be greatly appreciated!